# Equivalence of the definitions of the Axiom of Continuity

Tags: microeconomics

I am trying to understand this topic in more detail. Below are the definitions of the Axiom of Continuity given by different authors. Defn. 1 is given by Ariel Rubinstein and I have seen lecture notes using Defn. 2.

Def. 1: A preference relation  $(\succeq)$ on $X$ is continuous if for $r \succ s$, there exists balls $B_r$ and $B_s$ around $r$ and $s$ (respectively) such that for every $x$ in $B_r$ and $y$ in $B_s$, we have $x \succ y$.

Def. 2: $\text{(Part 1)}$ If $x_n \rightarrow  x$ and $x_n \succeq y$ $\forall \ n$ then $x \succeq y$, and $\text{(Part 2)}$ if $x_n \preceq y$ $\forall \ n$ then $x \preceq y$.

---

My questions:

1. I have seen Defn. 1 and Defn. 2 in microeconomic books. I do not find them to be equal; in fact, Defn. 2 is the converse of Defn. 1. Isn't it so?
2. Many authors simply write that *"if A is more preferable to B and B is 'sufficiently close' to C, then A is preferable to C"*. If I am to go through Def. 2 and write it in a more formal way, then can Part 1 and 2 of Def. 2 correspond to (or be re-written as) Part 1 and 2 (respectively) as in the following new Def. 3:
   $$\text{(Part 1) } (A \succeq B) \land (A \rightarrow C) \implies C \succeq B \\ \text{(Part 2) } (A \succeq B) \land (B \rightarrow C) \implies A \succeq C$$

Comment: [Rubinstein's lecture note](https://arielrubinstein.org/gt/arielDocs/downloadme.asp?id=5#page=30) actually have a proof of the equivalence of the two definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following 4 conditions.

1. If  $x \succ y$ there is a ball $B_r$ around $x$ such that for all $z \in B_r$, $z \succ y$.
2. If $y \succ x$ there is a ball $B_s$ around $x$ such that for all $z \in B_s$ we have $y \succ z$.
3. if $x_n \to x$ and $x_n \succeq y$ then $x \succeq y$.
4. If $x_n \to x$ and $y \succeq x_n$ then $y \succeq x$.

Consider the sets
$$
\begin{align*}
&UC(y) = \{x: x \succeq y\},\\
&LC(y) = \{x: y \succeq x\},\\
&SUC(y) = \{x: x \succ y\},\\
&SLC(y) = \{x: y \succ x\}.
\end{align*}
$$
We have the following equivalences:

- 1 is equivalent to the assumption that $SUC(y)$ is open.
- 2 is equivalent to the assumption that $SLC(y)$ is open
- 3 is equivalent to the assumption that $UC(y)$ is closed
- 4 is equivalent to the assumption that $LC(y)$ is closed.

We also have that:

- $SUC(y)$ is the complement of $LC(y)$.
- $SLC(y)$ is the complement of $UC(y)$.

We also know that a set is open if and only if its complement is closed. From this it follows that $1$ is equivalent to $4$ and $2$ is equivalent to $3$.

Alternatively you can also proof it directly

**Th** 1 is equivalent to 4

*proof* ($1 \to 4$) Let $x_n \to x$ and $y \succeq x_n$. Towards a contradiction assume that $y \not \succeq x$ which means that $x \succ y$. Then we know that there exists an open ball $B_r$ around $x$ such that for all $z \in B_r$, $z \succ y$. But for $n$ large enough we have that $x_n \in B_r$, so for $n$ large enough also $x_n \succ y$, which is a contradiction.

$(4 \to 1)$. Assume that $x \succ y$ and assume that for all open balls $B_r$ around $x$ there exists an $z_r$ such that $z_r \not \succ y$, which means that $y \succeq z_r$. Take a sequence $r_n \to 0$ which generates a sequence $z_n$ with $y \succeq z_n$ and $z_n \to x$. Assumption 4 then gives that $y \succeq x$, which gives the desired contradiction.

The equivalence between 2 and 3 can be shown in a similar way.

... continue answer

### Other continuity conditions

Consider in addition the following 2 conditions

5. If  $x \succ y$ there is a ball $B_r$ around $x$ and a ball $B_s$ around $y$ such that for all $z \in B_r$ and $w \in B_s$, $z \succ w$.
6. If $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$ and for all $n$, $y_n \succeq x_n$ then $y \succeq x$.

Let us first show that these two are equivalent

**Th** $5$ is equivalent to $6$.

*proof* Assume that $5$ holds. Let $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$ with $y_n \succeq x_n$ for all $n$. Towards a contradiction assume that $y \not \succeq x$. Then $x \succ y$. As such, there should be a ball $B_r$ around $x$ and $B_s$ around $y$ such that for all $z \in B_r$ and $w \in B_s$, $z \succ w$. Now, for all $n$ big enough $x_n \in B_r$ and $y_n \in B_s$. As such, for $n$ big enough $x_n \succ y_n$, a contradiction.

For the reverse, assume that $6$ holds $x \succ y$ and, towards a contradiction for all balls $B_r$ around $x$ and $B_s$ around $y$, there are $z \in B_r$ and $w \in B_s$ such that $w \succeq z$. Let $r_n \to 0$ and $s_n \to 0$ then we can generate a sequence $z_n \in B_{r_n}$ and $w_n \in B_{s_n}$ such that $z_n \to x$, $w_n \to y$. And for all $n$, $w_n \succeq z_n$. this gives (by $6$) that $y \succeq x$, a contradiction.

### Connecting the various conditions together

Remember from the first part the following two conditions:

7. $\forall x, y$, if $x_n \to x$ and $y \succeq x_n$ for all $n$ then $y \succeq x$ $\leftrightarrow$ $\forall y$, $LC(y)$ is closed, $\leftrightarrow$ $\forall y$, $SUC(y)$ is open
8. $\forall x, y$ if $y_n \to y$ and $y_n \succeq x$ for all $n$ then $y \succeq x$ $\leftrightarrow$ $\forall x$, $UC(x)$ is closed $\leftrightarrow$ $\forall x$, $SLC(x)$ is open

The following result shows the equivalence between $5$ (or $6$)$ and $7$ and $8$. It is also exercise 3.C.3 in MWG (if you would be interested). The proof is not so self-evident.

**Th** $5$ (or equivalently $6$) hold if and only if both $7$ and $8$ hold.

*proof* That $5$ (or $6$) imply $7$ and $8$ is obvious as we can take the constant sequence. For the reverse, assume that $7$ and $8$ hold and that $6$ is not true. This means that $x_n \to x$, $y_n \to y$, $y_n \succeq x_n$ for all $n$ and $x \succ y$. Then as $SUC(y)$ is open, there is an $N_1$ such that for all $n \ge N_1$:
$$
x_n \succ y.
$$
As $SLC(x)$ is open, there is also an $N_2$ such that for all $n \ge N_2$:
$$
x \succ y_n.
$$
There are two possible cases.

1. There is an $N_3$ such that for all $n \ge N_3$:
   $$
      x_n \succeq x.
      $$
2. There is a subsequence $k(n)$ such that for all $n$
   $$
      x \succ x_{k(n)}.
      $$

If $1.$ is the case, then for all $n \ge \max\{N_3, N_2\}$,
$$
x_n \succeq x \succ y_n,
$$
a contradiction.

If $2.$ is the case, then we can find an $m$ such that $k(m) \ge N_1$. Then:
$$
x \succ x_{k(m)} \succ y
$$
As $SUC(x_{k(m)})$ is open and $x_n \to x$, we know there is an $N_4$ such that for all $n \ge N_4$:
$$
y_n \succeq x_n \succ x_{k(m)} \succ y
$$
Taking the limit for $n \to \infty$ we see that:
$$
y \succeq x_{k(m)} \succ y.
$$
again a contradiction.

Comment: Do you mean Defn. 2 and Defn. 3 are equivalent? I think you said exactly the opposite the other day and that has still kept me confused. (Because I find Def. 2, 3 to be equivalent.)

Comment: I do not as well see how $B_r \ni x \succ y \in B_s$. Your answer probably just shows $x \succ r$ and $y \prec s$.

Comment: In fact, I don't see how exactly the statements 1 and 2 combined is equivalent to Defn. 1 of mine. I don't understand the double limit case there.

Comment: @dictatemetokcus Sorry, but I also have a life... and sometimes other stuff to do, which means that I can't continuously check and respond to queries. If you don't like my answer, just downvote. I completed your question and fixed the typo in 1. I also had some looking up to do as the argument is not that simple. I hope you're happy now. (?)

Comment: @dictatemetokcus btw, if you want me to delete the answer, just let me know (no problem).

Comment: Right, the fact that you were not responding at all even to my previous questions and yet continuously answering me got me triggered. Not that I did not appreciate your efforts, I absolutely did. I have a more concise solution now, and I will add it as an answer later. Nevertheless, for your efforts, I believe I should pass the reputation to you.